# Using revenuecat sandbox with a trial

Tags: app-store-connect, appstore-sandbox, revenuecat

So I'm using revenuecat to handle in-app purchases for my Flutter app - right now only hooked up with the iOS. I want to test how it works with a trial (Introductory Offers via App Store Connect).

I'm logging the purchase response I get back from RevenueCat and it looks like

flutter: PurchaserInfo{entitlements: `EntitlementInfos{all: {all_plans: EntitlementInfo{identifier: all_plans, isActive: true, willRenew: true, periodType: PeriodType.normal, latestPurchaseDate: 2020-12-09T22:49:06Z, originalPurchaseDate: 2020-12-09T22:48:15Z, expirationDate: 2020-12-09T22:54:06Z, store: Store.appStore, productIdentifier: 2, isSandbox: true, unsubscribeDetectedAt: null, billingIssueDetectedAt: null}}, active: {all_plans: EntitlementInfo{identifier: all_plans, isActive: true, willRenew: true, periodType: PeriodType.normal, latestPurchaseDate: 2020-12-09T22:49:06Z, originalPurchaseDate: 2020-12-09T22:48:15Z, expirationDate: 2020-12-09T22:54:06Z, store: Store.appStore, productIdentifier: 2, isSandbox: true, unsubscribeDetectedAt: null, billingIssueDetectedAt: null}}}, latestExpirationDate: 2020-12-09T22:54:06Z, allExpirationDates: {2: 2020-12-09T22:54:06Z}, allPurchaseDates: {2: 2020-12-09T22:49:06Z}, activeSubscriptions: [2], allPurchasedProductIdentifiers: [2], firstSeen: 2020-11-16T00:03:13Z, originalAppUserId: $RCAnonymousID:c38c01542e7a4a7cb674d76147e71f84, requestDate: 2020-12-09T22:53:43Z, originalApplicationVersion: 1.0, originalPurchaseDate: 2013-08-01T07:00:00Z, managementURL: itms-apps://apps.apple.com/account/subscriptions, nonSubscriptionTransactions: []}`

The latest expiration date is 5 minutes from now (which is expected) - when I do go live (not using the sandbox account) would the latestExpirationDate be a month from now (since it's a monthly subscription) or a week from now (the trial end date)? And if not then which field should I be looking at for the trial end date? It's not clear to me with a sandbox account, I'd love it if someone could help me know how I could test the trial stuff with RevenueCat

Thanks

Comment: Expiration date will be the expiration date of the current period - in this case the trial expiration date.

Comment: @enc_life so it will be a week after (if the trial is one week) and after the week is over, then that field will be replaced by the monthly subscription?  

Also is there a way to see this when testing the app before we go live?

Comment: That's correct! It should all work the same way in sandbox, except the durations are condensed. There unfortunately is no way to alter the sandbox renewal durations.

Comment: ok great - thank you!